# Why the infinitive in Portuguese "Cartago tem que ser destruída"?

Tags: syntax, portuguese, infinitive

> Cartago tem que ser destruída.

"Carthage must be destroyed." I'm wondering about the infinitive (*ser*): where does it come from? In what situations is the infinitive used after *que*: only with *ter + que*, or also with other verbs?

It looks strange to me, because I don't know of any similar construction in the other Romance languages. But it is not at all unlikely that I missed parallels: does a similar construction exist in any of them?

I know it doesn't exist in Latin: so in what way could it have developed from Latin constructions? Is it perhaps a combination of *quod* and the accusative with infinitive? I would appreciate any information that could help me put this construction in a broader perspective.

Comment: I would like to post a comment but I can't. Indeed, the correct translation in this case would be _Cartago tem de ser destruída_. _Ter de_ express obligation, necessity, desire while _ter que_ has as complement _something_, _anything_.
If you read portuguese, you can read more in:
http://embomportugues.blogs.sapo.pt/44634.html and http://www.brasilescola.com/gramatica/ter-que-ou-ter-de.htm

Comment: There's a very similar construction in Spanish, _tener que_ + Inf, which is also a periphrastic Necessary modal, equivalent to English _have to_ + Inf. I'm quite sure neither existed in Latin. They're all novel syntactic constructions that avoid the swamps of modal auxiliarity. And the modal is required because Cato's original sentence used a gerundive, which expressed a Necessary modal sense of the original verb. The use of infinitive is probably just a recent development.

Comment: An equivalent construction is also found in Spanish: 'tiene que ser destruída" sound fine and is [in wide use](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Cartago+tem+que+ser+destru%C3%ADda.#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22tiene+que+ser+destru%C3%ADda.%22&pbx=1&oq=%22tiene+que+ser+destru%C3%ADda.%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=625l625l7l1172l1l1l0l0l0l0l83l83l1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=9a76dcb319f2a4f&biw=1280&bih=699).

Comment: @Beatrix, I converted your answer to a comment. Regarding the "tem de" versus "tem que", it's just a matter of taste (and prescriptivist nitpicking). "Cartago tem que ser destruída" is a perfectly grammatical sentence, at least in Brazilian Portuguese. It also expresses necessity, in the same way as "tem de", "precisa" ou "deve", as Mark Beadles pointed out.

Comment: @Beatrix: My Portuguese is *cough* rusty, but I read your second link and was able to understand it. Otavio came up with a similar suggestion, which I interpreted as that there is some elliptic noun (*tem algo que [è?] para ser*). That seems to match your linked page, more or less. But that doesn't seem to fit here, since *Cartago* is the subject, and it seems very hard to supply the ellipsis here, if there is any. Or do you mean to say that *que* is incorrect here? If that is so, that just shifts the question to why the tendency exists for people to still use *que* here.

Comment: @Jlawler & Mark: Very interesting, thanks for pointing out the Spanish construction! Jlawler: You're right that neither construction existed in Latin; the closest I can get to an infinitive of necessity would be the poetic attributive infinitive, which can express finality (please don't ask me to look it up in Kühner-Stegmann). So I was wondering how it came to be. Periphrasic *habere* + *ad* + gerundive seems familiar; but then we're still a long way from *tener que* + inf.

Comment: Well, many Latin verb forms became homophonous in the vulgar languages due to lenition, loss of cases, etc. E.g. `URBEM UIDENDĪ` 'to see Rome' and `URBIS UIDENDAE` 'for Rome to be seen' both became URBE VIDENDE. So, the periphrasis arose. Many periphrastic forms use prepositions (Romanian has a special preposition just for infinitives), but some do use the relativizer _que_. But I have no idea what led some forms to use _que_ and some to use (e.g.) _de_.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: Hmm I'm not sure I understand. How did the merger of gerund and gerundive (which is in any case interesting) lead to a periphrastic construction? In both of your examples, there isn't really any sense of necessity or finality that I can see.

Comment: The phonological merger meant that meaning was obscured; in a sentence like `CUPIDUS SUM URBE VIDENDE` one could not tell which sense was meant. So speakers used analytic constructions to clarify. But I don't know why particular forms were chosen. `ESSE` + gerundive carries the sense of necessity while `ESSE` + gerund does not, but confess I don't fully understand what happened between there and _ser_ + particle + infinitive.

Comment: @MarkBeadles: There was no difference in meaning between *cupidus Urbis videndae* and *cupidus Urbem videndi*, at least not in classical Latin; neither had any sense of necessity or obligation. The gerundive only had this sense where it could *not* be replaced with a gerund, as in the famous quotation from Cato. So I don't quite see what this merger has to do with it, unless there *was* a difference in meaning in Vulgar Latin before the merger, somehow?

Comment: I know nothing about the exotic and far-away Romance languages, and I don't know if it's relevant; but English of course requires the infinitive after the modal auxiliary 'ought' as in "Carthage ought to be destroyed".

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut: Right, that's true; but that is auxiliary + infinitive, which is not so uncommon. This is comparable to "Carthage ought that be destroyed".

Comment: I don't think anything about the construction looks even the slightest bit odd. (Near native Spanish speaker). When I was taking Iberian History in Spain, the teacher told us the original phrase was `DELENDA EST CARTAGO`.

Comment: @SerdarOrtaç: Why does it not look odd to you? Do you know of any other constructions that have *que* + infinitive? The Latin phrase is *ceterum censeo Carthaginem delendam esse*.

Comment: @Cerberus ...because I don't know of any similar construction in the other Romance languages.... Cartago tiene que ser destruída [ES]. Cartago tem de que ser destruída [PT]. Other meanings-- No tiene nada que ver con Cartago. (It is irrelevant to Carthage) [ES] `Qué más le queda que hacer?` (What more do you have left to do?) [ES]

Comment: @SerdarOrtaç: Should not the fact that you don't know of any similar construction in the other Romance languages make it look odd to you? // *No tiene nada que ver con Cartago.* — You may be on to something here! I know this is not exactly the same, but couldn't it be that some kind of ellipsis of *nada* or another negation is how this construction came to be?

Comment: @Cerberus Sorry about that confusion, I was quoting you. :) `...because I don't know of any similar construction in the other Romance languages....` First I gave the same construction in another Romance language, then I gave two other examples from another Romance language.

Comment: I'm studying Portuguese right now and just the other day asked my teacher a similar question, and he told me that "ter que" is slightly less strong than "ter de" -- "ter que" being closer in strength to "should" and "ter de" closer to "must".

Comment: In French it is the same: Carthage a besoin d'***être*** detruite / Carthage doit ***être*** détruite

Comment: @sergiol: That is not quite the same: it would be like saying *Carthage a besoin qu'être détruite / Carthage doit qu'être détruite*.

Comment: @Cerberus: Yoou asked why the infinitive. Not why the "que".

Comment: @sergiol: My question was intended to be only about the infinitive after *que*. Elsewhere, an infinitive would be unremarkable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way to figure out "why" a construction  has to be a certain way 
is to see how it got to be that way, or whether it is usual or not for a language to do things this way. There are three issues:

1. How does a verb meaning "to possess" develop a meaning where it expresses obligation
2. Why does the following verb of the embedded clause appear in the infinitive?
3. Why is *que* rather than *de* or something else used as a subordinator?

As for (1), Heine & Kuteva (2002: 333) name seven frequent grammaticalization sources for the concept of OBLIGATION. These are COPULA, DO, GET, NEED, OWE, H-POSSESSIVE, SUITABLE.
(An H-possessive is "a marker of predicative possession expressed, for example, in English by *have*". (ibid.: 163)). So let's take it on their authority that it is frequent cross-linguistically for *have*-like verbs to end up expressing obligation. The fact that *ter* is, or is related to, a verb helps us to explain why this particular construction has to involved two linked clauses: a matrix clause containing the verb *ter*, and an embedded clause describing the obliged action.

On a side note, use of Latin *habere* does actually show up in this sense. (See towards the bottom of the [CNRTL entry for](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/avoir) *avoir*). The quote from Varro that is cited is "rogas ut id mihi habeam curare"

So, why is an infinitive used in the embedded clause? Here we can note that cross-linguistically, constructions involving two linked clauses often have a *pivot-controller relation* (see Van Valin 2005: ch.4) holding between arguments of the two clauses. An argument of one clause which is expressed (the "controller") is understood to be coreferential with an unexpressed argument (the "pivot") of another clause. Since the person who is obliged to do an action is normally the one who is doing the action, it makes sense for this construction to have a pivot--controller relation where the subject of the matrix clause will be the same as the subject of the embedded clause. The relevant property of the infinitive is that it is not marked for its subject; this is fine since it is unnecessary to indicate the subject. (I don't speak Portuguese, but I am guessing that you couldn't use one of the personal infinitives in place of the regular infinitive in this construction)

Why *que* instead of some other subordinator? My partial guess is that because the construction probably developed from one with similar meaning, but where *ter* has an object, e.g. "Tenho trabalho que fazer", it will just take the subordinator from that construction.  Note that in French, for example, which has a similar construction *avoir à + INF*, the relevant form with an object for *avoir* uses *à* to introduce the infinitive: "j'ai ce travaille à faire".

Heine, B.; Kuteva, T. (2002). World Lexicon of Grammaticalization. CUP [please do not illegally consult the copy posted on scribd.com by some unscrupulous person]

Van Valin, R. (2005). Exploring the syntax-semantics interface. CUP.

Comment: That's right. The personal infinitives are not used in this construction.

Comment: I think you are absolutely right! In `Tenho trabalho que fazer.`, the emphasis is on the work, and needing to do it is secondary in . In `Tenho que fazer trabalho.` the emphasis is on the duty, and it seems more urgent. I bet the `ter que + infinitivo` just came about as a result of switching emphasis off the verb to convey urgency.

Comment: Oops I forgot to accept your answer! Very thorough exposition. I was mainly wondering about the use of the conjunction where I would have expected a preposition, and you've answered that too, though as a "guess". If you ever find anything can confirms this, don't hesitate to notify me.

Answer (score 5):

Periphrastic modal constructions of the form 'have to' + infinitive are found in several Romance languages.

Spanish: *haber/tener de/que* 'have to'+ infinitive;

Portuguese: *haver/ter de/que* 'have to' + infinitive;

Several Southern Italian varieties also have this construction but it is mostly found in Ibero-Romance languages. In some Ibero-Romance languages this construction has expanded to take on aspectual meaning (eg in Abruzzo *tenere a* + infinitive expresses durativity) while in some other Romance languages (eg Sardinian) it is used to express future time reference.

This construction is rarer in the other Romance languages: French has *avoir á/être á* + infinitive while Italian has *avere/essere da* + infinitive, but the role of the construction is much more limited than in the Ibero-Romance languages.

The historical development of this discussion is discussed in *"[Verbal periphrasis in Romance](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=zTa23cfRGzMC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)"* by Mario Squartini. In summary it was a process of grammaticalisation that occurred late in the development of the modern Romance languages and is still ongoing in some of them.

Comment: About Sardinian, we both have "aere" (from [hăbēre](http://www.dizionario-latino.com/dizionario-latino.php?lemma=H0001800&parola=habere&md=ff&v=no) I suppose) and "tennere", but at least in my variety, we only use the first one to form the future, I think (I'm always trying to think of counterexamples, but can't find anything).

Comment: @Alenanno Thanks for inserting the full reference, I was a bit lazy! And I've slightly re-worded for clarity.

Comment: @Alenanno So what form does the construction have in Sardinian? I would guess something like *aere a* + infinitive?

Comment: Exactly. That's the structure. The translation is not just "future", it can also be interpreted as "future intention" too I think. Unfortunately, there aren't actual grammars for Sardinian like for other languages, as it is mostly spoken.

Comment: @Alenanno Okay, so the construction still has a modal (irrealis) function, but it also marks futurity.

Yes, there doesn't seem to be a single comprehensive grammar of Sardinian, but there's the work of Eduardo Blasco Ferrer, and [this work](http://www.amazon.com/Sardinian-Syntax-Romance-Linguistics-Michael/dp/0415049229) on Sardinian syntax.

Comment: Yes there are works, even dictionaries, but you'll find people saying "hey, it's not true that we say that", because there are tons of small varieties. :D Thanks for the link!

Comment: Great comparative answer! I am now mainly wondering about the combination of *que*, which normally introduces a finite verb, governing an infinitive in this construction. So Spanish and Portugese have this, and the southern-Italian version can perhaps be explained by Spanish rule over Naples and Sicily (ca. 1500–1716). What development could explain this usage of *que*? Should I edit my question to better reflect this focus? I just didn't quite know what exact thing to focus on when I asked my question.

Answer (score 3):

User [Beatrix](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/610/beatrix) had posted an answer that has been deleted. It contained some useful information that I will summarize here.

Beatrix suggested that some consider the use of *ter que* without a direct object to *ter*, as in my Question above, to be bad style (although others disagree). There is [the idea](http://www.brasilescola.com/gramatica/ter-que-ou-ter-de.htm) that *tenho de* is used to express "I have to [verb]", while *tenho [noun] que* is used with a direct object to mean "I have [something] to [verb]". It would then be recommended that *ter de* be used when *ter* does have a direct object, while *ter que* is to be used when there is such a direct object, because *que* is a relative pronoun that refers to an antecedent.

If we assume that this idea comes from somewhere, leaving aside stylistic issues, it supports the hypothesis that *ter que* with no direct object to *ter* developed from the older *ter [object] que*, as suggested by Lovegren above.

Comment: I agree with this. I also don't see why it's weird, "I have things to do" -> "I have to do things." "Tenho coisas que fazer." -> "Tenho que fazer coisas."

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves: Why is that not weird? It is not normally possible in similar languages to turn a relative pronoun into a conjunction and then having it introduce an *infinitive*.

Comment: I am going to have to disagree. The `que` here is not serving as a relative pronoun, instead it's an auxiliary word. It's functioning the same here as it is in English `to`, as in "I have `to` go", in fact the exact choice of auxiliary word is arbitrary. In European Portuguese you may also use `de` in place of the `que`, "Eu tenho `de` sair" is also correct. Even in German, `zu` functions as an auxiliary verb in "haben `zu` in "Du hast `zu` gehorchen." (You have to obey.)